# How to prevent elementary OS from closing all applications after waking a long lock period?

Tags: release-loki

For quite a days now I am having this sort-of bug in elementary OS whereby If I put my laptop to lock mode for a long period (like overnight) each and every applications are closed by elementary OS. I have disabled suspend and my hardware doesn't support "halt", So I put my laptop always to lock mode.

N.B: I am using a custom kernel by Xanmod

Comment: Don't use a custom kernel. That's the root of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the issue is related to the custom kernel
but I had an issue like that in elementary and it was fixed by the latest updates
so you can just

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Yes my installation is upgraded to the latest releases!!

Comment: can you post a log